# Creating a dynamically updated progress bar with Rails/Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, user-interface

**This is my first "general" SO question - I'm not looking for anyone to write a single line of code for me, I just need some advice**

I'm looking for a method to implement a progress bar/thermometer (ideally in jquery) that updates dynamically as users enter data into a form in my Rails app. I'm not concerned with the value of the fields of the form, just whether they are filled out or not. Individual fields will have hard coded weights (i.e. filling out your name gives you 1 point, email 10 points, etc) that increment the count/percentage of status bar in a very ajax-y, asynchronous way. I don't want to have to post or refresh to see the status of the progress bar.

I have a feeling I'm going to have to use some premade jquery library like one of the following:

1. **[Jquery ProgressBar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar)**
2. [ProgressBarDemo](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php#)

Here's the kicker: I can't even fathom to to get these progress bars to accept data from user input in my Rails FormHelper forms. I've looked at all the API docs and class methods and have no idea where to start!

How about it SO? Can you point this n00b in the right direction? any good examples I could look at?

Thanks in advance!

~Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could just do the entire thing via jQuery. This is how I would imagine it working - i.e. not writing the code but more helping you think this one through.

Firstly, you have several inputs, let's just say there are 5 to make it easy and they are all of type text.

```
<input type="text" name="first" value="" />
<input type="text" name="second" value="" />
<input type="text" name="third" value="" />
<input type="text" name="fourth" value="" />
<input type="text" name="fifth" value="" />
```

Then let's assume that also means that each one is worth 20% and that your progress bar starts at 0 when you enter the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 0
});
```

Then the simple thing to do would be to update that value when each element is changed.

First look for changes:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    // Code goes here to update
});
```

Them really the next thing you need to remember is that value is both a getter and a setter. So simply get the value, assign it to a variable, then update the value, which would probably look something like this.

```
currentValue = parseInt($("#progressbar").progressbar('value')) + 20;
$("#progressbar").progressbar('value',currentValue);
```

Again, I haven't tested this, but it's my best guess as to how to very easily do it.

Comment: Scratch that, I gave it a quick test and you can see the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchmalone/HrmGe/

Comment: If I could give you 500 upvotes I would! Now if I can just figure out how to get the progressbar value to decrement/decrease if the field is cleared.

Comment: The progressbar is not displaying in both those fiddles now. Any idea why? I tested in multiple browsers. It worked awesome last night (or morning for you I guess! ) ~Dan

Comment: The reason is that my server with the CSS resource died :-(

Comment: I've got the basic functionality working in my app. Can't thank you enough man!

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what Mitch said. I'd suggest to use the `focusout()` event that jquery provides. Then you can check each input box for its content once the user leaves it.