# Rails progress bar when parsing a file (not uploading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, progress-bar

I'm currently working on a project that parses large Excel and XML documents, inserting them into a database. This can sometimes take some time, so I'd like to feed a progress bar back to the user, so they've got some idea of how long this will take. I've seen a couple of methods to show progress bars for files that are uploading, but nothing for parsing a file and adding content to a database as I am doing. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: You could use jQuery as described in this discussion:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812665/creating-a-dynamically-updated-progress-bar-with-rails-jquery

Comment: You can get records count on the start of the parsing. After that divide it by 100, so you get record count that values as 1% of total excel document records. Inside your parsing algo just update progress every time % is changed. Use this progress on front end with something like jQuery-ui progressbar.