# Progress bar in a Rails app for parser

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, parsing, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I made the rails app that parses one website. I wonder, whether it is possible to show the process of the parsing in a progress bar which will be shown on a main page(to start the process you need to click the button)? I think I need to use bootstrap for view of progress bar, but how to pass the process of execution itself into view of bar?

Edit:
The parser itself is situated in the model that stores result to the database after each step i. e. if parser detects first company and its data - save, then the second company and so on. The progress bar will show result based on information from database(I don't understand how to use ajax for this) and I really want to use bootstrap progress bar, not jquery bar.

My model-parser

```
class PrintingHouses < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.print-index.ru/default.aspx?p=84&gr=198')

sum=0

loop do
  page.search('.goodname .goodname').each do |n|
  link = Mechanize::Page::Link.new(n, agent, page)
  new = link.click
  name = new.search('#ctl00_ctl00_BaseCentralRegion_CentralRegion_lblGoodName h1')
  address = new.search('.address')
  phone = new.search('.phone')
  email = new.search('.email')
  website = new.search('.www')


  PrintingHouses.create(name: name.text.center(100), address: address.text.strip,
                       phone: phone.text.strip, email: email.text.strip,
                       website: website.text.strip)
end
num = page.search('.goodname .goodname').count
sum=sum+num
break unless link = page.link_with(:text => " » " )
page = link.click
end

puts sum

end
```

This question is marked as a duplicate but I didn't find anything that could help me so please help.

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions on StackOverflow which will take you a long way, for example _[Progress Bar for Background Process in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14388579/454094)_ and _[Creating a dynamically updated progress bar with Rails/Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4812665/454094)_. Read them and you will be better equipped to ask questions more specific to the problems you are facing.

Comment: Too bad that cannot close this as the duplicate of the former as it does not have an accepted answer. As for the latter, it does not match the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

The gem [Progress Job](https://github.com/d4be4st/progress_job) looks promising for providing progress updates on background jobs. At this time it looks like it works with DelayedJob.